# Find which data split caused the job to fail in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I was wondering if I can get some help on how to debug this situation?

Basically, I am reading the data from hdfs.. perform some basic computation.. and write the result back to hdfs..

But in job tracker.. I see that one of the task is always in initializing phase?

```
Task                                         Complete           Phase .....     Counter
task_201312040108_0001_m_003006                 0                 Initializing  0
```

And after few attempts (3) this task failed.. forcing whole job to fail.. while rest of the others.. succeed...

How do I debug this situation?

I was wondering if i can take a look at what data split this mapper is getting...?? Oh.. this is a map only task..

Comment: Hadoop Java, Hadoop Pipes, or Hadoop Streaming?  Which version of Hadoop?

Comment: @JudgeMental: Java hadoop

Answer (score 0):

all my Java mappers extend a base mapper that has the following code:

```
// hook for subclasses
protected void doSetup( Context ctx ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {}

public final void setup( Context ctx )
throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String strSplitMsg = "Input split: " + ctx.getInputSplit();
    LOG.info( strSplitMsg );
    ctx.setStatus( strSplitMsg );
    doSetup( ctx );
}
```

so that I never get bitten by that problem.  However, your freeze might be happening before the call to setup(); perhaps you can look at the task tracker log on the host where the failures occurred or the task attempt log itself.